# How to create Android Things' bundle and push it over OTA?

Tags: android, iot, ota, android-things, android-things-console

Anyone succeeded creating Android Things Bundle and pushing it over OTA?

On the Android Things' Console, there's a page to [Create a Bundle](https://developer.android.com/things/console/app_bundle.html) for the OTA.

I'm trying to figure out how to do that. I've adding just a single APK file `main.apk` to a `ZIP` file. Then I've tried to push it to a RPi which is sitting nearby. But the main.apk would not be launched on the device.

Things I've tried/done:

- Download `Empty bundle` with `Things Build ID`=`NIH40K`
- Creating a Bundle and pushing it to devices through `OTA UPDATES`
- Creating a new `FACTORY IMAGE` with that newly created bundle
- Still my app would not be started
- I've checked, my app's MainActivity has [action=MAIN and category=IOT_CATEGORY](https://github.com/ViliusKraujutis/Android-Things-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L24)
- Tried running app from my laptop via `adb connect Andorid.local` and it works as designed

But I couldn't make an OTA update. Anyone succeeded doing so?

Here's my project on Github:
https://github.com/ViliusKraujutis/Android-Things-Demo

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are all the steps necessary to make OTA update possible after creating a new product in your android things console :

1 - Create your first build configuration, either from the empty bundle in the console or from a personnal bundle you added.

2 - Download build of this build configuration. You will get an Android Things image. Flash it to your RPi as you did when you flashed the Android Things regular image. https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#flashing_the_image

From now on, your RPi will check if a different version of your product has been pushed from the console. The check happens every 5 or 6 hours so you might have to be patient. Also your RPi needs to have internet access.

3 - Upload another bundle to your console, create a build configuration for it and then push it to your devices via the OTA updates panel of your console.

4 - You will need to manually reboot the RPi to apply the update.

This article from Dave McKelvie is a good example in my opinion : http://android.geek.nz/hello-android-things-developer-console/

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with getting the main apk to run. Turns out if your custom animation is misconfigured the main apk will fail to load and it will never be launched. I solved the problem by installing a stock build with empty bundle. Using adb to connect and retrieve the existing animation. I then used this animation along with my main apk to create a bundle. I loaded this image on my device and my main app loaded just fine.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem. How did you retrieved the existing animation with adb? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Flash stock build with empty bundle on your board

Comment: 1. Flash stock build with empty bundle on your board 2. adb connect <your devices ip address> 3. adb shell 4. su 5. navigate to /system/media ensure that the bootanimation.zip file exists 6. exit to exit the shell 7. adb pull /system/media/bootanimation.zip <location you would like to move it to>