# Creating custom image of Android Things including my custom apps

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

I am planning to use Raspberry PI for Android Things project, I am able to flash default image (androidthings_rpi3_devpreview_4_1.zip), over it. I have installed my apps. Now is there a way to create a custom image with my apps included so that it can be shared with a customer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Android Things' bundle and push it over OTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835438/how-to-create-android-things-bundle-and-push-it-over-ota)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Android Things Console](https://developer.android.com/things/console/index.html) according [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/console/create.html) or tutorial in [this](http://android.geek.nz/hello-android-things-developer-console/) blog. Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44835438/6950238) question of [ViliusK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517381/viliusk) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881152/6950238) of [david couet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7962171/david-couet).

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the difference between the  custom image (custom image option while burning on the card its ask two option default or custom image) and bundle (which is ask to upload custom bundle or empty bundle on the console of android things ).