# How to upload a custom build configuration to Android Things with just a main.apk

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

I'm currently working with a **Raspberry Pi 3** and **Android Things** (with the official RPi touch screen), and I'm trying to understand the process of flashing a custom build.  I have already gone through the process of creating a starter build, and now I'm having issues with getting my `main.apk` booting up when I flash the image.  I have already viewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835438/how-to-create-android-things-bundle-and-push-it-over-ota) and it doesn't seem to illuminate why mine isn't working.

The AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="[...].thingstest">

<application
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--Launch activity as default from Android Studio-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--Launch activity automatically on boot-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The HomeActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
}
```

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="[...].thingstest.HomeActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="169dp"
    android:text="@string/pushme"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's really a simple app.  And it works over ADB, but does not boot when built into a bundle (Android Studio -> Build APK -> 7Zip -> Store into ZIP -> Send to Console -> Flash Build).  Any advice?  Are there naming conventions that I'm missing (as in do file names need to be specific)?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you see your package when you run `adb shell pm list packages`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It is listed.

Comment: Although when I try to start the app via adb, using `adb shell am start [package].HomeActivity` I get a `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat =[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=[package].HomeActivity}` .  Any guesses here?

Comment: Typically the format is `am start com.example.app/.MainActivity`

Comment: Thank you.  This is odd; it argues that the activity class does not exist.

Comment: I agree that's pretty odd. Can you do something similar with one of the sample apps and see if works in that case?

Comment: The Sample SimpleUI works perfectly.  I'll dig into this and figure out what went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't work, but creating a new Things-based project worked.  Thanks all.